# No permite ejecutar una pausa dentro de un bucle

Tags: javascript, html5, while, clase-anidada

Estoy intentando crear un reloj a partir de bucles while anidados pero no lo he logrado hasta ahora

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>reloj</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Reloj</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        h = 0;
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
        while (h <= 23) {
            while (m <= 59) {
                while (s <= 59) {

                    h++;
                }
                m++;
            }
            s++;
            document.write(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Lo he editado ahora hasta donde he logrado realizar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reloj</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border 1px solid black>
<tr>
<th>Horas</th>
<th>Minutos</th>
<th>Segundos</th>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var vueltash = 0;
var vueltasm = 0;
var vueltass = 0;
var a = "";
h = 0;
m = 0;
s = 0;

while (vueltash <= 23) {
while (vueltasm <= 59) {
while (vueltass <= 59) {

a = "<table border 1px solid black"
+ "<tr>"
+ "<td>" + vueltash + ":" + vueltasm + ":" + vueltass + "<td>"
+ "</tr>"
+ "</table>";
document.write(a);

vueltass++;
}
vueltasm++;
}
vueltash++;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Luego de crear el bucle, tengo que insertar el reloj en una tabla, Estoy complicado porque solo puedo utilizar bucles while

Comment: Un reloj o un cronometro?

Comment: un reloj, luego lo insertare en una tabla con filas y columnas

Comment: De acuerdo, has visto lo que te he mostrado en mi respuesta?

Comment: si, ahora mismo estoy tratando de entenderlo

Comment: Vale, espero te sirva, de igual forma estoy aca por si tienes dudas

Comment: solo que al ejecutar el código me queda una fila de numero en vertical

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63698/discussion-between-ivan-botero-and-condor12).

Comment: Ya te he agregado un ejemplo de como crear un reloj, no es necesario usar bucles

Comment: Ya he agregado una actualizacion a mi respuesta, usando bucles, tal como lo indicas, espero te sirve, estoy presto a tus comentarios

Comment: Creo que tendrías que documentar mas un poco respecto al uso de document.write y el uso de JavaScript, recuerda que este lenguaje corre del lado del cliente, y en todo lenguaje de programación *los ciclos de ejecutan rapidamente* si pretendes hacer un reloj usando bucles deberias considerar agregar una pausa entre cada repetición del ciclo

Comment: Me gustaria que por favor nos explicaras, porque solo debes usar bucles? Sabiendo que estos tienen esa particularidad para escribir sobre el DOM

Comment: pues tiene que ser así, es un trabajo y aunque si podría hacerlo fácilmente con las opcones que han puesto aquí, lo han complicado un poco y me han limitado las opciones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Primer Error

En tu código estas haciendo esto:

```
while (h <= 23){ 
 while (m <= 59) { 
  while (s <= 59) {
    h++;
  }
  m++; 
 }
s++;
}
```

**¿Que ocurre?**

Se va a repetir infinitamente, ya las iteraciones del tercer bucle no se detendrán ya que la variable evaluada `s` nunca aumenta realmente su valor.

---

### Primera Solución

```js
h = 0;
m = 0;
s = 0;
while (h <= 23) {
  while (m <= 59) {
    while (s <= 59) {

      s++;
    }
    m++;
  }
  h++;
  
  document.write(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>reloj</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Reloj</p>

</body>

</html>
```

### Explicación

Solo debes re-ordenar las variables que estas ejecutando en tus bucles, haciendo que cada una aumente realmente su valor.

```
while (h <= 23) {
  while (m <= 59) {
    while (s <= 59) {

      s++;
    }
    m++;
  }
  h++;  
}
```

---

### Segundo Error

No deberías usar `document.write()` para mostrar un texto que debería aparecer en un solo lugar, para hacer un reloj es mejor que hagas algo como esto:

```js
function mostrarHora() {

  var today = new Date();

  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();

  m = agregarCero(m);
  s = agregarCero(s);

  document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

  var t = setTimeout(mostrarHora, 500);
}

/**
 * Agrega un 0 si el numero esta entre 0 y 9
 */
function agregarCero(i) {

  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };

  return i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="mostrarHora()">
  <div id="reloj"></div>
</body>
```

---

### Explicacion

Simplemente usamos la función `Date()` de Javascript y la llamamos recursivamente, haciendo que se genere un reloj, de modo que se obtengan los minutos y los segundos de manera continua y en un mismo lugar.

---

## Actualizacion -> Usando Bucles

### Codigo

```js
async function iniciarReloj() {

  /* Valores iniciales */
  var hora = 0;
  var minuto = 0;
  var segundo = 0;

  /* Contenedor del reloj */
  var contenedor = document.getElementById("reloj");

  /* Contenido del reloj */
  var reloj;

  while (hora <= 23) {

    while (minuto <= 59) {

      while (segundo <= 59) {

        reloj = agregarCero(hora) + ":" + agregarCero(minuto) + ":" + agregarCero(segundo);

        contenedor.innerHTML = reloj;

        segundo++;
        await sleep(1000);
      }

      minuto++;
      segundo = 0;
    }

    hora++;
    minuto = 0;
  }

}

/* Iniciamos el reloj */
iniciarReloj();

/**
 * Se encarga de realizar una pausa, por N milisegundos
 */
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

/**
 * Agrega un 0 si el numero esta entre 0 y 9
 */
function agregarCero(i) {

  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };

  return i;
}
```

```html
<div id="reloj"></div>
```

---

### Explicacion

He usado las sentencias `await` y `async` de Javascript, las cuales de acuerdo a cierta [documentación](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/asyncawait-en-javascript/):

> En lugar de tener que utilizar la respuesta de la primera petición en un incómodo then( function(){} ), usando la palabra especial await podemos usar getFilm() y getMain() como si devolvieran valores síncronos en vez de promesas.

Lo que nos da a entender que este tipo de modificadores esperaran al resultado de una funcion, es por ello que hemos agregado:

```
await sleep(1000);
```

Para que permite la espera de 1 segundo antes de continuar con cada una de las instrucciones.

---

### [Ver ejemplo en linea](https://jsfiddle.net/syra1rbb/5/)